# When should I start repotting bonsai Juniper?

Tags: bonsai, repotting

Are January and February good months to repot evergreen bonsai Juniper. This would be my first time repotting it and the plant is doing great so far, but I don't want to kill it: I want to make sure that I do it at the right time of year.

Comment: What season do you guys have in January & February?

Answer (score 4):

In winter around the end just before spring is a very good time to repot your bonsai.  Repotting at this time can make space for the roots' growth in spring.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what part of the world you are located. I live in pacific northwest in Washington state. We have pretty mild winters here in the Puget Sound so I am able to repot my juniper starting in early to mid February. I will give them extra protection from frost and wind until they are re-established in their new pots.